# Wifi Enable Android Emulator for PC

Tags: android, emulation

are there any Wifi Enable Android mobile Emulator for PC.i want to run android device on pc and also it should be enable wifi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Genymotion. It use Virtualbox in backend. So you can modify properties of the VM in Virtualbox to connect it directly (bridge mode) to the hardware.

http://www.genymotion.com/